# Problem with disk unmounting on sleep and mounting on wake

Tags: usb, mount, suspend

I use a HTPC with XBMC on Lubuntu 13.10 (32 bits) to watch My DVDrips from an external
USB HHD, the problem comes when I put the computer to sleep from between XBMC
and then I wake up the system then I see an error message on the resumed XBMC screen
that says “Unsafe device removal!” and when I go to the Lubuntu Desktop I see a dialog window
with the available option for removable media. The weird thing is that when I plug in a 16gb penstick 
from Sandisk (cruzer extreme) and sleep and wake the computer the error message in XBMC 
does not appear and neither the window on the desktop,

why can't my external HHD also stays mounted on sleep?

I would really appreciate some help.

PS: I have S3 system power state on BIOS, I also check the power options with cat /proc/acpi/wakeup and all USB appear to have S3 enabled.

Comment: Does the external HDD have a separate power source besides the USB?

Comment: The HHD doesn't have an external power source.

Comment: Can this problem be related to a mounting problem? My HHD is in NTFS format.

Comment: I haven't heard of any issues with NTFS, though that might play a role. Try checking out [this forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1919132).

Comment: I tried a lot to fix this problem, but in the end I just gave up, now I switched to Ubuntu 12.04 and everything works like it should, Ubuntu is not fun, everything works OOB!